# How to avoid Apache "Internal Server Error" if one of LDAP AuthProviders is not reachable?

Tags: apache, authentication, ldap

Im using LDAP authentication for a Website with *two* AuthBasicProviders in Apache.
If one of the LDAP-Servers is not reachable (e.g. because: server is down or its network is not reachable), I get an "Internal Server Error" if the UID to be authenticated comes from this LDAP-Server.

How can I catch this situation and return a friendly message instead. Something like:
**"Sorry, we are currently not able to check your authentication."**

- The UIDs are unique for both ldap-servers.
- If I put the "ldap_remote" in front and it is not reachable
  => it always fails (the "ldap_local" will not by asked).
- If I put the "ldap_local" in front, it will be searched at first
  and if the UID is there => Fine (password correct or not).
- But if the UID is not on "ldap_local", the "ldap_remote" will be asked.
  If ldap_remote is reachable => Fine (correct password or not).
  But if it is not reachable => "Internal Server Error" :-(

I use the following in my Apache2 config:

```
  # this one is always reachable
  <AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap_local>
    AuthLDAPUrl  ldap://127.0.0.1/dc=mycompany,dc=com
  </AuthnProviderAlias>
  # Not always available
  <AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap_remote>
    AuthLDAPUrl  ldap://xyz.mycompany.com:389/dc=mycompany,dc=com?sAMAccountName
    AuthLDAPBindDN       ldapadmin@mycompany.com
    AuthLDAPBindPassword xxxxxxxxx
  </AuthnProviderAlias>
  # and later ...
  <Location /foo >
    AuthName "foo at my-server"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider  ldap_local ldap_remote
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
```